# Generate swagger documentation for Play sird dynamically

Tags: scala, playframework

Most of the already available projects for auto-generating swagger docs for Play Framework (Scala) are using the traditional `routes` files, i.e., https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger.

Are you aware of anything similar that uses Play Scala Sird Router instead of the traditional `routes` files?
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaSirdRouter

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to play-swagger for auto-generationg documentation would be Tapir https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir which is a library for describing HTTP endpoints in a type-safe way.